# VSCode debugging typescript application library

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on breaking up a monolith into separate libraries (as a pre-cursor to moving to a microservice based architecture)

The extraction of the first couple of libraries has gone well, but I've now got to the point of needing to debug into one of these libraries as part of the main application.

We're using a mono-repo managed using rush, and a vscode workspace.

I've tried many different versions of launch.json options, with no luck.

The key problem is that any break points I set in one of the library projects is never mapped when running the main application.

Is this possible? Or do I have to accept that debugging these extracted libraries will be painful until we have them as completely isolated microservices that can be run independently?

I've not been able to find any useful articles online for setting up debugging large nodejs projects in vscode

> Note - I will put together a quick example repo when I have a few mins, but any suggestions in the mean time will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. I'm in a similar boat.

Comment: @WarrickFitzGerald - no, unfortunately not. If you figure it out please let me know!

Comment: I did figure it out. launch.json needs to have "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/../YOURLIB/**"

Comment: basically if you don't have YOURLIB in there vscode will ignore it. vscode will only look for breakpoints in files that are covered in resolveSourceMapLocations